# What is the best way to handle configuration files with git?

Tags: git, hook, directory-structure

Say my application has a configuration files in plain-text. They contain some sensitive information which is required to test the application in my dev environment. I use different OSes to access and work on my projects (win, mac, ... ).

I do not wish some of the information in the configuration files to make it to my public git repository. In best case I want the sensitive information to be replaced with placeholders and have the configuration files uploaded to the repository to keep track of their structure.

---

### How would you approach the problem?

The hook itself wouldn't be much of a problem for me to write. I'm more interested how to tie it all together, possible directory structure, etc. I'm quite new to git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a convention followed in the Django world that you could use - there is a standard `settings.py` file that imports a `local_settings` module at the end if there is one available.

Have all your secret stuff in that `local_settings.py` file and add it to `.gitignore` so that it doesn't go to the repository. This way, people will know that they can add their own settings to `local_settings`.

For example,

`settings.py`:

```
DATABASE_USERNAME = 'your username here'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'your password here'
```

`local_settings.py`:

```
DATABASE_USERNAME = 'my top secret username'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = 'my top secret password'
```

The best part is that whatever you've defined in `settings.py` will get overridden by the same name in `local_settings.py`.

Comment: Simple and nice idea, I like that.

Comment: Was what I was looking for. We code in PHP, Yii and we can inherit the config with some local changes.
main.php -> local.php
.gitignore local.php